# A question on $G$-map

Tags: representation-theory

I have a question that in studying representation theory and definition of $G$-maps we started with "Let $(\rho,V)$ and $(\rho',V')$ be two representation of $G$ over a field $F$. A linear map $T: V \to V'$ is called a $G$-map if it satisfies the following $\rho'(g)T=T\rho(g)$ $\forall g\in G$.....................$(1)$

Now my question is this same $T$ serves the condition for any representation $\rho$ and $\rho'$. Because I was studying the corollary of Schur's lemma i.e

Corollary. "Let $(ρ, V )$ be an irreducible representation of $G$ over $\Bbb C$. Let $T : V → V$ be a $G$-map. Then $T =λ.Id$ for some $λ∈\Bbb C$ and $Id$ is the identity map on $V$.

Proof. Let $λ$ be an eigen-value of $T$ corresponding to the eigen-vector $v ∈ V$ , i.e., $T (v) = λv$. Consider the subspace $W = ker(T − λ.Id)$. We claim that $W$ is a $G$-invariant subspace. Since $T$ and scalar multiplications are $G$-maps so is $T − λ$."

----Now upto that part if we can take $\rho=\rho'$ then $T-− λ$ is a $G$ map. So I can take any representations on $V$ after taking $T$. Is my this arguement true. Because I am stuck in this conception that for a particular $G$ map $T$ whether any representations will satisfy the condition $(1)$ or not. If this arguement is not true then please explain when $T$ and scalar multiplications are $G$-maps why $T − λ$ is a $G$-map?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that I don't really understand what you're asking, but it seems to me that you're confused. Let me try to make a few comments that might shed some light on the matter.

A representation $(\rho,V)$ is a vector space $V$, equipped with a $G$-action $\rho$. A morphism of representations $(\rho,V)\rightarrow(\rho',V')$ is then a morphism of vector spaces which is simultaneously a morphism of $G$-sets, i.e. a vector space homomorphism which commutes with the $G$-action. This is precisely what your definition is saying.

So now Schur's lemma says that the set of endomorphisms of an irreducible representation is precisely the set of scalar multiples of the identity. It seems to me that you're asking whether this implies anything about morphisms between *non-isomorphic* representations.

Here's the thing. An endomorphism of a representation is also an endomorphism of the underlying vector space, so first of all the representations have to be defined *on the same vector space* in order for this to make any sense at all. This is a much bigger deal than you might expect -- OK, all vector spaces of dimension $n$ ($n$ finite) are isomorphic, but this isomorphism isn't at all natural. So this means that if you have a (nonzero) endomorphism $\varphi$ of $(\rho,V)$, and choose another representation $(\rho',V')$, you can only ask whether $\varphi$ is a morphism $V\rightarrow V'$ if $V=V'$.

But this clearly can't be the case for $\rho,\rho'$ irreducible and non-isomorphic. Indeed, because we have $V=V'$ we can consider the actions $\rho$ and $\rho'$ *with respect to the same basis of* $V$. So then $\rho\not\simeq\rho'$ means that there exists a $g\in G$ such that $\rho(g)\neq\rho'(g)$, in which case you clearly can't have $\rho'(g)\varphi(v)=\varphi(\rho(g))$.

Here's a trivial example. The group $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has two irreducible representations: the trivial representation $triv$ and the sign representation $sign$. These are defined *on the same space* -- namely $\mathbb{C}$ -- and so let's assume that we have a nonzero endomorphism $\varphi$ of $triv$. This is then a scalar multiple of the identity. Suppose now that $\varphi$ is a morphism $triv\rightarrow sign$. Realizing $G$ explicitly as $G=\{\pm 1\}$, consider what happens at $-1$. If $\varphi$ were a morphism $triv\rightarrow sign$, we would have $sign(-1)\varphi(v)=\varphi(triv(-1) v)$. But $\varphi=\lambda\cdot Id$, so this says that $-\lambda v=\lambda v$, so you have a contradiction (unless $\lambda=0$, but we assumed that $\varphi$ was nonzero).

Comment: My question was in the Corollary. "Let $(ρ, V )$ be an irreducible representation of $G$ over $\Bbb C$. Let $T : V → V$ be a $G$-map. Then $T =λ.Id$ for some $λ∈\Bbb C$ and $Id$ is the identity map on $V$." 

Is $\rho=\rho'$ and $V=V'$ or not?

Comment: I think the example you have given it implies that $T:V \to V$ and $T\rho(g)=\rho(g)T$ $\forall g \in G$ am I right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. $T$ is a map $V\rightarrow V$. How can this possibly imply anything about $V'$? I don't understand your second comment either. Of course a scalar multiple of the identity will be a $G$-map for a given representation; it just represents a change of basis given by scaling by $\lambda$. The example is an example of how $\lambda\cdot Id$ cannot be a $G$-map between non-isomorphic representations.

Comment: Perhaps what you're trying to get across is the following question: "if $\rho,\rho'$ are representations of $G$ on the same space $V$, and $\lambda\cdot Id$ is a $G$-map $\rho\rightarrow\rho'$, then is it the case that $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are isomorphic? If so then the answer to this is clearly yes -- scaling by $\lambda$ is an automorphism of $V$!